# How to downgrade nuget version of which I have on cmd?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line, msbuild, nuget

I mistakenly upgrade nuget on cmd with "nuget update -self"(which upgrade automatically to V3.5), and I want to downgrade this to old version (2.8.6) (to be the same as in current production version)

how can I downgrade / uninstall nuget (and then install the old)?

I searched for downgrade nuget / uninstall nuget, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no installer for NuGet.exe. Different versions of NuGet can be downloaded from the NuGet site:

```
https://dist.nuget.org/index.html
```

Just download the version you want and use that to replace the version you want. Or you can just copy NuGet.exe from your production server and replace your local copy.

Comment: where can I found nuget.exe? in C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet I see just Visual Studio 2015 folder, and the nuget.exe there is not the one I just upgraded to (since its "date modified" is from 2016).

Comment: Inspect the PATH environment variable to find the installation directory.