# How to install a specific version of nuget?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm troubleshooting some issues with specific versions of nuget and msbuild, hence need for downgrading of nuget versions:

[Build failures with Mono 5.14.0.177, msbuild 15.0, nuget 4.7.1 on Travis CI, but not reproducible in VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988395/build-failures-with-mono-5-14-0-177-msbuild-15-0-nuget-4-7-1-on-travis-ci-but)

Nuget can be updated to latest version with this command:

`nuget update -self`

However installing a specific version of nuget seems to be unsupported, this still install the latest version of nuget:

`nuget update -self -Version 4.6.2`

And this fails with nuget not found error:

`nuget install nuget -Version 4.6.2`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update

---

EDIT:

Looking at nuget source code the developers made an assumption that update should always happen to the latest version:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/3803820961f4d61c06d07b179dab1d0439ec0d91/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Common/SelfUpdater.cs#L85

```
// Check to see if an update is needed
if (package == null || version >= package.Version)
```

Very sad decision, Microsoft! Hence submitted a PR and it was rejected:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/2422

Comment: To my mind Update implies that you install version which is more than your own version and their code is correct.

Comment: @AccessDenied only update flag allows to self-update nuget, but install flag does not support this. Installing usually means installing from "scratch", hence this separation.

Comment: Just like what you have found, the command `nuget update -self` update the nuget.exe to the latest version. If you want update it to the specific version, how about download the nuget.exe from nuget.org manually: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.6.2/nuget.exe, then replace old version with that downloaded?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT there is no obvious reason why nuget cannot be downgraded by itself. As you can see from my PR it is just one small change in the nuget code.

Comment: @denfromufa, Yes, so I think your PR is reasonable, but I don't think it has a high priority. Is there any reason for you have to use the **command** to upgrade nuget to the specified version? If not, you can temporarily consider using my previous suggestions. MS will consider your PR.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213164/how-to-downgrade-nuget-version-of-which-i-have-on-cmd

Answer (score 1):

> How to install a specific version of nuget?

According to the document [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference):

> Each download is the nuget.exe file directly. Instruct your browser to
>   save the file to a folder of your choice. **The file is not an
>   installer**; you won't see anything if you run it directly from the
>   browser.

We could to know, NuGet.exe is not an installer. You can just download the version what you want from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads), then replace the one on the local disk.

Although NuGet team provide the command line `nuget update -self`, which can be used to update the `nuget.exe` to the latest version, just like what have you said, nuget update command not support update nuget.exe for a specify version. So, I think your PR is reasonable, but it should be at a low priority. Because we can update `nuget.exe` by downloading manually.

Hope this clear and helps.

Comment: If you feel that was a useful PR, then perhaps you might leave a supporting comment on it? The PR was rejected with little explanation.